# My .htaccess is not working properly

Tags: apache-http-server, php, webserver, htaccess, extension

This is very bizarre.  I have never had this issue until now.

Basically I have a little code in .htaccess that removes the .php extension from the web pages.  For some reason, it has stopped working for me. Localhost and live server give the same error if I go the webpage without .php extension. Weird thing is, I have the exact same .htaccess file being used for another site and it works perfectly fine on both localhost and same live server.

I would like to know what might be causing this?  Here's the code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you look at your apache log?

Comment: If you don't add any other information, no one will be able to guess what is causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it works if I add spacing to it like this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It shouldn't so that would mean there is something wrong with the file's encoding or some invisible characters.